# Postfix domain not found

Tags: postfix

I have set up postfix on a server that has to send all output from root to R*****@gmail.com - But the problem is that when it sends mail it tries and sends to "root@rene-desktop" which I am notified via gmail:

"Your message was not delivered to the root@rene-desktop because the domain rene-desktop was not found. Check if there are spelling errors or excess spaces and try again."

I just want the following: Root ---------> My gmail. (Not root@rene-desktop)

What can the problem be?

```
Sudo nano main.cf
myhostname = localhost.localdomain
mydestination = localhost localhost.localdomain
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
compatibility_level = 2
```

---

```
sudo nano /var/log/mail.log
Jan 29 13:35:55 rene-desktop postfix/cleanup[1686]: F1E494016EB: message-id=<20190129123555.F1E494016EB@localhost.localdomain>
Jan 29 13:35:56 rene-desktop postfix/qmgr[1313]: F1E494016EB: from=<root@rene-desktop>, size=420, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 29 13:35:57 rene-desktop postfix/smtp[1690]: F1E494016EB: to=<root@rene-desktop>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[108.177.119.108]:587, delay=1.7, delays=0.02/0.06/0.61/1, ds$
Jan 29 13:35:57 rene-desktop postfix/qmgr[1313]: F1E494016EB: removed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An email message with an unknown domain won't be accepted/routed by Gmail.

Furthermore, an email from root@ any domain won't be accepted either, but my memory might be betraying me.

If you need those emails accepted to gmail, you need to change/mask them to a valid domain in the Internet.

Those restrictions are not specific to the gmail service, since the 90s that email routing rules have been tightened up by email service operators to fight spam.

For rewriting your outgoing email address in `postfix`, you have to do:

Add to your `main.cf` file:

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

Now create a the `/etc/postfix/generic` file with the contents:

```
root@rene-desktop your_email@gmail.com
```

It is however not enough creating the `generic` file, you have to tokenize it for `postfix` to use it. Do then to create the `generic.db` file:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/generic
```

Now restart postfix and you should have that email mapping in place.

Comment: Yes I know ... But how do I change the setup in postfix so that it does not send to "Root@rene-desktop" but to my gmail "R********@gmail.com" I am well clear over it can't send to that mail ...

Comment: I don't know how to change it in the postfix reason I ask

Comment: Sorry, did not understand from the question you were aware of it. Added the steps to the answer.

Comment: I lacked these commands in my main.cf:  alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, myorigin = /etc/mailname, inet_interfaces = loopback-only
After I had added them it work :)

Comment: No : https://serverfault.com/questions/133326/postfix-how-do-i-make-email-aliases-work

Comment: Sudo newaliases :)

Comment: @ReneMortensen Which in itself calls `postalias`... but yeah, I had forgotten it ;) I remembered you had to run something. ;-P It is already sometime since I had to deal w/ QMail and Postfix in a daily bases.